# Sitecore Forms Captcha Validation Message showing intermittently

Tags: sitecore-forms, recaptcha

we are using `Sitecore forms` with `Captcha` for forms validation.

1. If we are doing a hard refresh (first-time load), It will not show a validation message for captcha.

[image]

2. If we refresh the page a second time, it will load, and on submit button, the captcha validation message is showing.

[image]

We are using `Sitecore 9.3` with a multilingual website and passing the language with the script of captcha as shown below.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. After adding the captcha script above script, as shown in image[image]
2. Removing an async keyword from validation referencing script of captcha
   [image]

It works for me. Thanks